# Save raster to USGS DEM Format in R

Tags: r, raster

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54351860/how-does-one-open-a-usgs-dem-download-in-r):

I would like to know how to do the reverse and save an .img raster image into a USGS DEM format.

Based on [GDAL docs](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/usgsdem.html), it seems like it would be possible but when I run `rgdal::getGDALDriverNames()` in R I get the following:

```
name       long_name                                                            create  copy isRaster
139         USGSDEM                          USGS Optional ASCII DEM (and CDED)  FALSE  TRUE     TRUE
```

which seems to imply that it won't create these files?

I was hoping to do something like:

```
library(raster)

# read
img <- raster("Raster_100ft_2022_10_18.img")

# convert to DEM
writeRaster(img, 'test.dem')
```

But `raster` doesn't seem to recognize that output format.

Is there some other method to save as USGS DEM files?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me it works with `terra`. If that's proper "USGSDEM" file, that's another question. From gdal reference it should save the file as well: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/usgsdem.html

```r
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- terra::rast(f)
terra::writeRaster(r, filename = "test.dem", filetype = "USGSDEM", overwrite = TRUE)

raster::raster("test.dem")
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 90, 95, 8550  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#> extent     : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> source     : test.dem 
#> names      : elevation 
#> values     : 141, 547  (min, max)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `terra::describe("test.dem")[1]` returns "Driver: USGSDEM/USGS Optional ASCII DEM (and CDED)"

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz, that seems to work.  Although I had some issues with my source file, I had to first convert it to tif, and then reproject to WGS84 for the above to work.  I'm not sure if USGSDEM format requires WGS84 projection?

Comment: @DarwinsBeard, from https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/usgsdem.html it seems, that WGS84 is not mandatory. And I guess in your case `img <- raster("Raster_100ft_2022_10_18.img") |> terra::rast() |> terra:write(....)` should work.